# Bluetooth keyboard wrong keymap

Tags: bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 15.10 and I bought this keyboard: Rii Mini i8+ Bluetooth https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01BDS1YZC/ref=cm_sw_r_other_awd_CHJfxbQC1A2B0

It's working perfectly on my android phone (5.1.1), but on my pc it has a completely different key map (German is selected, but it doesn't matter):
It's mostly only a num block. M=0, j=1, u=4, 7=7, k=2 and so on.

According to some comments on amazon, it's also plug and play on Raspberry Pi.

On ask Ubuntu are several posts about Bluetooth keyboard, but they are all other problems.

PS: my old ps/2 keyboard works fine

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add output of `lsusb`? May be some with same keyboard come with a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth Keyboard - Wrong Keymap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836866/bluetooth-keyboard-wrong-keymap)