# Bluetooth Keyboard - Wrong Keymap

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, keyboard-layout

I successfully paired my new Bluetooth keyboard (Netway, 77 keys, Win/MAC), but it works only as a numerical keyboard. What I mean is that I am able to write only numbers over few letters in the right part of the keyboard and the rest doesn't work!

I saw the same problem without any answer here: [Bluetooth keyboard wrong keymap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759113/bluetooth-keyboard-wrong-keymap)

I prefer to buy another keyboard, than to modify a whole keyboard layout :P

Thank you guys for any possible answer.

Comment: have you tried testing the keyboard with other devices and changing your keyboard layout

Comment: Firstly - Thank you for your answer Jonluke! Yeap, it works great just with my phone (Android), also I crossed over couple of different layouts and nothing change. The comunication between keyboard is without any problem, but there is no way to write something....
Is there any way how to use the driver from Windows for Linux, or that is impossible?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is due to Numlock activating, resulting in part of the map being interpreted as a numeric keypad, and the rest doing nothing. At least with Apple compatible keyboards, the solution is to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> a couple of times to toggle Numlock off. You should also look into editing `/etc/numlockx` to disable Numlock by default. There is also a Gnome or X tweak mentioned at [Apple Keyboard – Numlock on Apple Wireless Keyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Numlock_on_Apple_Wireless_Keyboard).

Comment: Just to say, had this problem with my old apple keyboard (the keymap was bizarre - only numbers 6-9 were working correctly). If you can install numlockx (e.g. `apt install numlockx`) then you can turn numlock off via commandline with `numlockx off` - had to do this, as unfortunately Fn+F6 didn't work for me at all.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me a lot, but the answer was much simpler in my case. I had a wired keyboard connected to my computer besides the Apple bluetooth keyboard. NumLock was activated there. I just pressed the NumLock button in my other keyboard and things worked like a charm. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I would like to echo Gustavo Martineli Massola's answer.
(https://askubuntu.com/users/1072784/gustavo-martineli-massola)

As I was setting up the Apple Bluetooth Keyboard I had a separate wired keyboard with NumLock on.

Someone with more reputation please get Gustavo an upvote!